# arrange the div in sequence format using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on scenario where when I enter number in the textbox i need generate dynamically div's. Actually I am struggling not aligned properly with the current div. Then I need to generate ID's for the div's. For this also code is available but the code not considered the default div as preview1 then it has to go on like preview2, preview3 so on. The div has to arrange sequence like first it has to show preview1......

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("inputAdd_page");
var totalCount = 0;
inputElement.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    var count = this.value;
    // Gaurd condition
    // Only if it is a number
    if (count && !isNaN(count)) {
        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
            spancount = document.createElement('span');
            prevPage = document.createElement('div');
            navbutton = document.createElement('button');
            preview_PageSize = document.getElementById('page');

            navbutton.className = "div_navig";
            navbutton.setAttribute('id', ['pag_navg' + totalCount]);
            navbutton.innerHTML = [1 + totalCount];

            spancount.className = "spanCount";
            spancount.innerHTML = [1 + totalCount];

            prevPage.className = "preview_windowSize";
            prevPage.setAttribute('id', ['page' + totalCount]);
            prevPage.appendChild(spancount);


            prevPage.style.position = "absolute";
            preview_PageSize.appendChild(prevPage);
            //fragment.appendChild(prevPage);
            fragment.appendChild(navbutton);

            totalCount++;
        }
        inputElement.value = "";
        document.body.appendChild(fragment);
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/7j7vxbkv/)

Thanks in advance.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I get you right, change the javascript as follows:

```
//prevPage.style.position="absolute";            
//preview_PageSize.appendChild(prevPage);
prevPage.style.width="100%";           
preview_PageSize.parentNode.insertBefore(prevPage, preview_PageSize);
```

Comment: hi @ram thanks for the comments I modifed the above code as prevPage.style.width=(2/count)*100 + "%";   the Id has to consider the default div also. could you please help me on that

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your notes, please have a look

Comment: hi @ram really thanks for the reply but still i am not getting the solution it coming as one below the other but it has to the default div should be on the top the next div should be below of the top div then id was not mapped correctly

Answer (score 1):

to improve positioning, you could apply a diffrent class to the child elements, like so:

```
prevPage.className = "preview_windowSize_element";
```

and use CSS:

```
.preview_windowSize_element {
position: absolute;
left: 31px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

to start with page ID 1 you could modify your script:

```
prevPage.setAttribute('id', ['page' + (totalCount + 1)]);
```

Comment: hi tom thanks for the reply but the default div should be page0, then page1.... kindly help me

Comment: hi mahadevan, this reverses the order of elements preview_PageSize.insertBefore(prevPage, preview_PageSize.childNodes[0]);

Comment: edited the fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7j7vxbkv/16/) Is _div with id="page0" on top of the others_ what you need?

Comment: thank you so much almost perfect but if i enter 2 in the input field i need to get three buttons because already one div was available so can i give like this navbutton.innerHTML = [2 + totalCount];

Comment: you could check if it's the first run, and if so increase count by one: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7j7vxbkv/22/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you search something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7j7vxbkv/5/)?.

I just add a `left` position in each `div`, because you set them to `position:absolute`.
So I added this line:

```
prevPage.style.left= (26 * totalCount) + "px";
```

I just put `26` like this, it will be the width of the button

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but the div has to above the current div with the same width and height

Comment: So, add the two line of code:
`prevPage.style.width= 24 + "px";`
`prevPage.style.padding = "5px 0px";`
`24` is the width of the button, it changes according to the text into the button